# Authenticate user and using the ChangePassword Control

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication

I have a webpage that a user logs into to.  Now I want to provide the ability for a user to change their password using the ChangePasswork Control.  The control does work as described here [ChangePasswork Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx#the_changepassword_control) for non-authenticated users.  But I want to the behavior for authenticated users.

I'm fairly new to asp so this could be a simple question but exactly how do you "authenticate" a user?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx#the_changepassword_control), the control works for both authenticated and non-authenticated users.
Changing a users password programmatically is very straight forward.
Take a look at the [MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) and [MembershipUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.aspx) classes.
You can validate a user using: MembershipProvider.ValidateUser
To authenticate them use: FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie
MembershipUser has a method: ChangePassword.
If you are new to all this, read [introduction to membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)